# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras' in AI DevCloud Intel

Tags: python, keras, intel

I'm trying to run `qsub myjob` but I'am getting an error. Here what I've done so far:

1. `conda create -n myenv intel python=3`
2. `source activate myenv`
3. upgraded some libraries:

   `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade keras`
   `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow`
4. created myjob file with this lines inside:

> ```
>  #PBS -l nodes=1
>  cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
>  echo Starting calculation
>  python NASNet.py
>  echo End of calculation
> ```

5. Executed `qsub myjob`
6. I'm getting this error:

> ```
>     from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
> ```

I did a test using `python NASNet.py` instead of `qsub myjob` in the terminal it worked perfectly. Why is it not recognizing keras when I'am using `qsub`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! It seems that we need to activate the environment in the script file, add this line `source activate myenv` in the file as follows:

```
#PBS -l nodes=1
source activate myenv
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
echo Starting calculation
python NASNet.py
echo End of calculation
```